# Print (generate) a code128 barcode (or any image) in millimeters (php)

Tags: php, printing, barcode-printing, code128

I need to generate labels with `code128 barcodes` in `PHP`.
These will be printed by users with almost any printer.

I have some specific sets of requirements:

- narrow bar width should be between 0.375mm and 0.5mm
- maximum overall barcode width: 115mm
- first 8 digits must use subset B
- remaining 20 digits must use subset C
- code must be readable at high speeds

I tried several barcode libraries but most of them don't allow stating the minimum bar width in millimeters. You are just able to scale the narrow bar width in fixed integer increments, and 1 is too small and 2 is too big :)

I also tried resampling the image using the gd lib, but the code becomes unreadable at high speeds.

Should I build my own code generator? 
If so, how would I generate the bars in millimeters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about editing a barcode library to add that functionality ?

Comment: I hate to break it to you - but it's going to be damn near impossible to get measurements in millimeters without control over the printer. If a user has their DPI settings changed - it's off. If their printer isn't the most accurate, it's off. This will be a tough one without knowing the printers and computers used to print them.

Comment: Precise printing is out of the powers of the world wide web, unless you make the user install a plug-in. The less bad solution is generating a format like PDF (but even in that case the user can freely resize when printing).

Comment: So how does LibreOffice, Corel and lost of others allow you to draw a rectangle of 105mm x 54mm and then print it that way? I mean, how can I generate an image that way? I know they use vectors, but at some point this is rendered in pixels, yes?

Comment: rephrasing: How can I produce an image (in píxels) that would result in a printed rectangle of 105mm x 64mm at 300dpi?

Comment: I think I might have solved this by changing the ppi of the generated barcode and setting the <img> tag with a style indicating a total width in millimeters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I believe I found a solution that applies not to every browser and printer combination, but it suits me nicely.

I am using the barodegen php library found at [barcodegen](https://www.barcodephp.com/en) because it is the only one allowing me to specify a subset for some characters and another one for others.

In my specific problem, I can do this:

```
$setB = '%'.substr($vars->code, 0, 7);
$setC = substr($vars->code, 7);

$code_array = array(array(CODE128_B, $setB), array(CODE128_C, $setC));
```

And then parse $code_array into a barcode.

Now, the other problem is also simply solved by setting the point per inch of the generated barcode image. This is called, wrongly I think, DPI. Correct me if I'm mistaken, but DPI is a harware characteristic of a printer. You can't change that. PPI on the other hand, you can change.

In my problem I had a 244px wide image, and I needed it to print in more than 95mm.
barcodegen allows you to do this by calling

```
$drawing->setDPI(64);
// I do think they should rename this to setPPI
```

Now, after you have a 224px image with 64ppi, all you need to do is show it in an img tag like this:

```
<img style="width: 96.8375mm;" src="interlink_code128_barcode.php?code='.$code128.'" border="0">
```

the 96.8375mm is obtained by solving the simple equation, if the image contains 64 pixels in one inch, how much inches will occupy 244 pixels? And then you transform inches to mm

I haven't got confirmation that the barcodes can be read at high speeds, but I do see the printouts looking sharp! :D

Answer (score 0):

Hello perhaps this url may be of help. Millimeters may be your sticking point, because of individual printer configurations. However, if are configuring the printer, than no problem.
The URL: http://www.davidscotttufts.com/2009/03/31/how-to-create-barcodes-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

ZF Barcode will allow you to change thick of digits.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.barcode.creation.html

ans it supports code128.

```
  $config = new Zend_Config(array(
                    'barcode' => 'code128',
                    'barcodeParams' => array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK', 'thickWidth' => 10, 'thinWidth' => 5),
                    'renderer' => 'image',
                    'rendererParams' => array('imageType' => 'gif'),
                ));
  Zend_Barcode::factory($config)->render();
```

Comment: my bad, I see that Zend has these "renderers". But in your example you are using image renderer in which the default width of a module is 1 pixel.

Comment: yes, there are a few renderers Image, SVG and PDF.   And you can also extend any of them to just change what you need.

Comment: I must say that I did not have time to go into investigating the zend framework, but it does look interesting. In any case I solved my problem by playing with ppi and the img width. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to hit 115mm exactly. Here's one that will print at a little over 116mm on all three of my printers and from IE or Firefox. Adjusting the width to 19 gets you down to about 109mm...

I am using a separate png image for each symbol and stringing them together on the client side. The complete `Code128` symbology using this technique can be found at http://notionovus.com/blog/barcodes/html/code-128-barcode/

```
<img 
alt="104,{Start B}" title="104,{Start B}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AC3gAT0BDuLeG4IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 33,A:{A},B:{A}" title=" 33,A:{A},B:{A}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AFzgAZsBPUCFhSIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 34,A:{B},B:{B}" title=" 34,A:{B},B:{B}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AHTgAcsBVYSvxaMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 35,A:{C},B:{C}" title=" 35,A:{C},B:{C}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AHcgAREAmJf+YHwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 36,A:{D},B:{D}" title=" 36,A:{D},B:{D}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AE7gAX8BL1PJL4YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 37,A:{E},B:{E}" title=" 37,A:{E},B:{E}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AHLgAccBU7KPeu8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 38,A:{F},B:{F}" title=" 38,A:{F},B:{F}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AHOgAYkBFLOchfoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 39,A:{G},B:{G}" title=" 39,A:{G},B:{G}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AC7gAT8BDxDJjdQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 40,A:{H},B:{H}" title=" 40,A:{H},B:{H}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADrgAVcBG9SQg7wAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 99,A:{Switch C},B:{Switch C}" title=" 99,A:{Switch C},B:{Switch C}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AEQgAKsAZaZph30AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 01,A:{!},B:{!}" title=" 01,A:{!},B:{!}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADJgAMcAkzbyVIUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 23,A:{7},B:{7}" title=" 23,A:{7},B:{7}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ABIgAEcAM15OsZIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 45,A:{M},B:{M}" title=" 45,A:{M},B:{M}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AETgAWsBJQmo7lIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 67,A:{ETX},B:{c}" title=" 67,A:{ETX},B:{c}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AHpgAVcA2+hRyrMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 89,A:{EM},B:{y}" title=" 89,A:{EM},B:{y}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ACQgAGsARQRcPq8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 01,A:{!},B:{!}" title=" 01,A:{!},B:{!}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADJgAMcAkzbyVIUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 23,A:{7},B:{7}" title=" 23,A:{7},B:{7}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ABIgAEcAM15OsZIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 45,A:{M},B:{M}" title=" 45,A:{M},B:{M}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AETgAWsBJQmo7lIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 67,A:{ETX},B:{c}" title=" 67,A:{ETX},B:{c}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AHpgAVcA2+hRyrMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 89,A:{EM},B:{y}" title=" 89,A:{EM},B:{y}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ACQgAGsARQRcPq8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt=" 46,A:{N},B:{N}" title=" 46,A:{N},B:{N}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AEcgALEAaE/9r8gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30"><img
alt="106,{Stop}"title="106,{Stop}"src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAABAQMAAAA/57ZEAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADigARMA2dpJzT8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="30">
```

Comment: so, what you are saying is that I should build my own barcode by "concatenating" several <img> of the specific widths in millimeters?

Comment: I used to use barcode fonts back in 1987, but I had the same problem with control over the exact width of the final complete barcode and my customer wanted me to hit the mark pretty exactly. So I studied the PostScript language and created something similar to the above in PostScript. Thinking of a barcode as the tiniest series of dots and spaces and scaling up from practically invisible to full size gave me the control I needed. Last year I started looking around for another job and decided to modernize my 25 year old technique for the WWW. Easier when generated using javascript or excel.

Comment: I solved this by changing the ppi of the barcode image and setting the width of the img tag to be the correct one according to those ppi.